# Windows Authentication with OpenID Connect (OIDC) with Active Directory (AD FS)?

Tags: active-directory, openid, spnego

This is NOT about Azure, but about an on-premises offline Microsoft Active Directory system, based on Windows 2016/2019.

Our website uses OpenID with Microsoft Active Directory, but we want the user to be logged in automatically (SPNEGO?), when using Edge/Chrome from a PC that is member of the domain.

Any idea how to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [keycloak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keycloak) can help you here, it can be mediate between LDAP and OIDC.